# Morris Bar chart dynamic labels

Tags: javascript, charts, morris.js

Is it possible to setup label names from the hash which is sent to morris?

```
  Morris.Bar({
    element: 'mevsother',
    data: $('#mevother').data('result'),
    xkey: 'created_at',
    ykeys: ['me', 'rank'],
    labels: ['Me', 'Them']
  });
```

Hash exemple:

```
`[{"created_at":"2014-02-24","name":"John","me":0,"rank":0}...`
```

So I want that one of the label to take the value of the `name` how can I do this? So instead of `'Them'` to get the value of name: `John`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse your data as a variable and get the value from it. According to your hash it can be:

```
var result = $('#mevother').data('result');
var labels = ['Me', result[0].name];

Morris.Bar({
    element: 'mevsother',
    data: result,
    xkey: 'created_at',
    ykeys: ['me', 'rank'],
    labels: labels
  });
```